# 'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge' deprecated in ios 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

How to change this line since UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge is now deprecated in iOS 13..?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorviewstyle/uiactivityindicatorviewstylelarge?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

You can use "UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleMedium" or "UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge"

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleMedium     // Available 
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge      // Available

UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge // Deprecated
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite      // Deprecated
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray       // Deprecated
```

Comment: 'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge' is only available on iOS 13.0 or newer. i am using deployment target 11.0 and 'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge' is marked deprecated and 'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge' not available.

Answer (score 3):

UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge) deprecated on iOS13
remember to set white color for iOS13

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
      activityIndicator.color = .white // remember to set color

   } else {
      activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
   self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge];
}
else {
   self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.large)
```

//deprecated

```
activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      //Note:- `medium` and `large` are only available after iOS 13.0
      activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
   } else {
      activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
   }
```